# Calculating partial pressure: Difficult cubic equation in bulky Chemical Equilibrium numerical

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

The problem, which I found in a popular book for Physical Chemistry, written by Neeraj Kumar, is fairly simple, being simply 2 equations and 2 variables, yet its simplification is a nightmare.

> $\pu{5 atm}$ $\ce{AB(g)}$ and $\pu{0.5 atm}$ $\ce{BC(g)}$ are introduced in a reaction vessel and the following equilibriums are established:

$$\ce{AB(g) <=> A(g) + B(g)} \qquad K = \pu{10^{-7} atm}$$

$$\ce{BC(g) <=> B(g) + C(g)} \qquad  K = \pu{10^{-6} atm}$$

> If the equilibrium partial pressure exerted by $\ce{B(g)}$ is around $10^{–n}$, determine the value of $n$.

We start of by writing the simultaneous equilibriums

[image]

$$10^{-7} = \dfrac{x(x+y)}{5-x}\tag{...1}$$

$$10^{-6} = \dfrac{y(x+y)}{0.5-y}\tag{...2}$$

Dividing the 2 gives us:

$$10^{-1} = \dfrac{x(0.5-y)}{y(5-x)}$$

This further simplifies to:

$$y=\dfrac{5x}{5+9x}\tag{...3}$$

We now have $y$ in terms of $x$, so we can substitute $\mathrm{(3)}$ in either $\mathrm{(1)}$ or $\mathrm{(2)}$, but substituting in $\mathrm{(1)}$ gives an easier simplification.

Substituting $\mathrm{(3)}$ in $\mathrm{(1)}$:

$$10^{-7} = \dfrac{x(x+\cfrac{5x}{5+9x})}{5-x}$$

This simplifies to give us:

$$10^{-7} = \dfrac{x(9x^{2}+10x)}{(5+9x)(5-x)}$$

It was the simplification of this cubic equation which gave me a problem.

Generally, approximations can be taken in such equations (by simply looking at the value of $K$, we know that $x$ will be a very small number) but here I don't see any. We can neglect $x$ in front of 5 in the $(5-x)$ term, but I doubt that makes the simplification of the cubic equation any easier.

On plugging the equation into Wolfram Alpha, it gives the following results which can be viewed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B10%2C-7%5D%3DDivide%5Bx%5C%2840%299Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2B10x%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%295%2B9x%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%295-x%5C%2841%29%5D).

These are the results:

[image]

$x \approx 5 \times 10^{-4}$ is the only valid result in this case.

On plugging this value of $x$ into (3), we get:

y = $\dfrac{25 \times 10^{-4}}{5+9 \times 5 \times 10^{-4}}$ (we neglect $45 \times 10^{-4}$ in front of 5)

$$\implies y = 5 \times 10^{-4}$$

Therefore, the partial pressure of $\ce{B(g)}$ at equilibrium is $= x+y = 2 \times 5 \times 10^{-4} = 10^{-3}$

My only qualms are in solving the cubic we had initially:

$$10^{-7} = \dfrac{x(9x^{2}+10x)}{(5+9x)(5-x)}$$

Without Wolfram Alpha, how would we solve this cubic equation? Approximating $(5-x) \approx 5$ doesn't seem to help our case much. Is there any way to solve this without using a computer, simply using pen and paper?

P.S.: This problem was actually asked in 2013 to high school students in a written competitive exam called JEE, and in that exam, the students only have 5 to 6 minutes for each problem, so imagine the sheer skill required to solve such a difficult cubic equation and get the answer in that time-frame.

Comment: https://www.math.utah.edu/~wortman/1060text-tcf.pdf

Comment: Usually when the calculations are too tough JEE awards it as a bonus. One more thing, you have given only JEE and not specified whether it is Main or Advanced.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM I believe it was the the first year JEE Advanced was conducted.

Comment: Now coming to your question: I tried searching the archives on the JEE Adv 2024 website but could find none. https://jeeadv.ac.in/archive.html . It would be great if you could post the problem image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A relatively straightforward solution is to start with your two equations:

$$10^{−7}=\frac{x(x+y)}{5−x}$$

$$10^{−6}=\frac{y(x+y)}{0.5−y}$$

In both cases, the variable in the denominator is negligible relative to the constant, so we simplify both:

$$10^{−7}=\frac{x(x+y)}{5}$$

$$10^{−6}=\frac{y(x+y)}{0.5}$$

If we divide both sides of the second equation by 10 to make the denominator an integer, we see that both equations are identical except for replacement of $x$ with $y$, which tells us that $x=y$. That allows us to substitute $x$ for $y$ to yield

$$10^{−7}=\frac{x(x+x)}{5}$$
$$\implies 5\times 10^{-7} = 2x^2$$
$$\implies x^2=25\times 10^{-8}$$
$$\implies x = 5\times 10^{-4}$$
$$\implies x+y=10^{-3}$$
$$\implies n=3$$

Comment: Nice! I've never known a book problem to require solving a cubic equation. There always seems to be some simplification that reduces the problem to a quadratic at most.